How to clear client browser cache and reflect new changes every time client open website with NGINX?
I am running Direct react build on NGINX server on GCP VM. The issue I am facing again and again is, Earlier i was opening website as example.com when I added permanent redirection with NGINX config files to www.example.com it is getting treated as new website to browser where earlier example.com was opened. In private tab website is getting redirected to www.example.com. And in some browsers normal tab with www.example.com is making cache and new changes are not getting reflected.
Here is my configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/html;  # Path to your React build folder
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;  # Redirect all non-matching routes to index.html
    }

    # Serve static files normally
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$ {
        expires 6M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}

I just want where website is working as example.com there it should redirected to www.example.com and every time client visits to website it should show latest changes.
Please help.

You are explicitly adding a six-month-lasting Expires header to your .js files, which are essential react-based web site core files, didn't you see it? Additionally, if you want to prevent any client or intermediate caching, add Cache-Control: no-store HTTP header to your root location using add_header nginx directive.

add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
i have tired with this. but it is behaving the same way as it was.

Did you remove .js files from your regex?

yes i did. But it is not working.
